# Powershell Group Object in CSV and exporting it

Tags: powershell, csv

```
#foo.csv
No, Fruit, Quality, Units, Location
1, Orange, New, 10, Village
2, Orange, Fresh, 20, City
3, Apple, New, 15, Village
4, Grapes, Fresh, 25, City
5, Apple, Fresh, 30, City
6, Apple, Fresh, 35, City
```

With this data I want output in following way:
Fruit | Location | Quality | Units

I am not able to further group (sub-group?) data, and what I came with is below, but its not what I need:

```
Import-Csv "E:\foo.csv"  | 
Group-Object { $_.Fruit } | 
Select-Object -Property Count, 
    @{ Name = 'Fruits'; Expression = { $_.Name } }, 
    @{ Name = 'Location'; Expression = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Units -Sum).Sum } } | 
Export-Csv new.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```

I tried further:

```
Import-Csv "E:\foo.csv"  | 
Group-Object { $_.Fruit } | 
Select-Object -Property Count, 
    @{ Name = 'Fruits'; Expression = { $_.Name } }, 
    @{ Name = 'Location'; Expression = { $_.Location } },
    @{ Name = 'Quality'; Expression = { $_.Quality } },
    @{ Name = 'Units'; Expression = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Units -Sum).Sum } } | Sort-Object -Property Count | Format-Table -Auto
```

But data is blank.

Comment: You want to group by (`Fruit`,`Location`,`Quality`) and sum `Units`?

Comment: Yes, right, first group by Fruit, then location, then Quality and then show there respective sum in Units. Kind of pivot table. But would like to see variations, as I am learning PowerShell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group by multiple properties in the same time:

```powershell
Import-Csv "E:\foo.csv"|
Group-Object Fruit,Location,Quality|
Select-Object @{Name='Fruit'   ;Expression={$_.Values[0]}},
              @{Name='Location';Expression={$_.Values[1]}},
              @{Name='Quality' ;Expression={$_.Values[2]}},
              @{Name='Units'   ;Expression={
                  ($_.Group|Measure-Object Units -Sum).Sum
              }}
```

Comment: First I thought, I need to put on some nesting, but this is really great. Thanks for explanation.